# Ruby on Rails by Michael Hartl Chapter 9.41

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am working with Michael Hartl's tutorial. When I  run test I get this error:

```
 1) Authentication authorization for non-signed-in users when attempting to visit a   
protected page as non-admin user submitting a DELETE request to the Users#destroy action
Failure/Error: specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) } 
Expected response to be a redirect to <http://www.example.com/> but
was a redirect to <http://www.example.com/users>
# ./spec/requests/authentication_pages_spec.rb:81:in `block (7 levels)
in <top required)>'
```

Here is my authentication_pages_spec.rb. Code might be slightly diffrent than showed in tutorial examples. Those changes were necessary to pass recent tests. Up to this moment everything worked perfect.

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "Authentication" do
  let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } 
    subject { page }

  describe "signin page" do
    before { visit signin_path }

    it { should have_selector('h1', text: 'Sign in') }
    it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
  end

  describe "signin" do

    before { visit signin_path } 

    describe "with invalid information" do
      before { click_button "Sign in" }

      it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
      it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error', text: 'Invalid') }

      describe "after visiting another page" do
          before { click_link "Home"}
          it { should have_selector('div.alert.alert-error') }
      end
    end

      describe "with valid information" do     
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) } 
      before do
        fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
        fill_in "Password", with: user.password
        click_button "Sign in"
      end

      it { should have_selector('title',    text: user.name) }

      it { should have_link('Users',        href: users_path) }
      it { should have_link('Profile',      href: user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Settings',     href: edit_user_path(user)) }
      it { should have_link('Sign out',     href: signout_path) }

      it { should_not have_link('Sign in',  href: signin_path) } 

      describe "followed by signout" do
        before { click_link "Sign out" }
        it { should have_link('Sign in') }
      end
    end
  end

  describe "authorization" do

    describe "for non-signed-in users" do
      let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

      describe "when attempting to visit a protected page" do
        before do
          visit edit_user_path(user)
          fill_in "Email",    with: user.email
          fill_in "Password", with: user.password
          click_button "Sign in"
        end

        describe "after signing in" do

          it "should render the desired protected page" do
            page.should have_selector('title', text: 'Edit user')
          end          
       end
        describe "as non-admin user" do
          let(:user)  { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
          let(:non_admin) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }

          before { sign_in non_admin }

          describe "submitting a DELETE request to the Users#destroy action" do
            before { delete user_path(user) }
            specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) }
          end
        end        
      end
    end

    describe "in the Users controller" do

      describe "visiting the edit page" do
        before { visit edit_user_path(user) }
        it { should have_selector('title', text: "Sign in") }
      end

      describe "submitting to the update action" do
        before { put user_path(user) }
        specify { response.should redirect_to(signin_path) }
      end

      describe "visiting the user index" do
        before {visit users_path }
        it { should have_selector('title', text: 'Sign in') }
      end
    end


     describe "as wrong user" do
       let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
       let(:wrong_user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user, email: "wrong@example.com") }
       before { sign_in user }

       describe "visiting User#edit page" do
         before { visit edit_user_path(wrong_user) }
         it { should_not have_selector('title', text: full_title('Edit user')) }
       end

       describe "submitting a PUT request to the User#update action" do
         before { put user_path(wrong_user) }
         specify { response.should redirect_to(root_path) } 
       end
    end    
  end
end
```

Anybody got idea? Thanks for help & intrest!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your users_controller#destroy you have redirect to `users_path` instead of `root_path`(which you're expecting). Can you show your #destroy action?

Comment: I've changed user_controller#destroy and It works. Thank you Vadim!

Answer (score 0):

I've just been running through this chapter and had the same problem, but I don't think the accepted answer is correct, and here's why:

The destroy action in your Users controller ***should*** be redirecting to the users_path, not the root_path, because we want admins to be returned to the list of users after having deleted one, and we want to redirect any non-admins who are trying to issue DELETE requests back to the homepage.

After re-reading the section, I realised I'd missed a before filter in my users controller:

```
before_action :admin_user, only: :destroy
```

Adding that got the test to pass.